# ASP.net like form based authentication in WPF MVVM prism

Tags: wpf, authentication, mvvm, prism-4

Having working on WPF MVVM (prism) application, I would like to implement authentication as it is for ASP.NET form based authentication. I would like to restrict users going to screens where authorization is required. how can this be implemented in WPF application, as I am using  PRISM.

Comment: Updated my answer to a more suitable solution for you. hope it will help :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using [Regions](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/14/mvvm-and-prism-101-ndash-part-3-regions.aspx) to navigate within your application, then your viewModels can implement the [`IConfirmNavigationRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iconfirmnavigationrequest_members%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) interface.

There, you can use [`ConfirmNavigationRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iconfirmnavigationrequest.confirmnavigationrequest%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) which takes a callback, to determine if the user has access to the view, and if not, deny it.

Samples can be found [here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/290548)

Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) to learn more about this